# Don't override specific directory on server with git push

Tags: git, push, git-push

I am making a discord bot and running it on heroku. I have never used git before. The project folder I am pushing looks like this:

```
discord_bot
{
.git
admin
bot.py
imgs
Profile
requirements.txt
}
```

Images are added through bot commands and I do want not override the server's `imgs` directory with my local `imgs`. Can I push updates to the `bot.py` file without also overriding the `imgs` directory?
I am currently pushing by doing

```
git commit -am "message"
git add .
git push heroku master
```

Comment: `push` pushes a commit. A commit contains everything you put into it. You put things into it by saying `add`. You said `add .` which means add everything. So you added the `imgs` folder contents, so they are in the commit, so you pushed them. If you didn't want that to happen, you should not have added the `imgs` folder contents. You can tell git to ignore the `imgs` folder contents for purposes of `add .` by using a `gitignore` file, but if you've already added them, it's too late for that now; you have added, committed, and pushed.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to `git add` specific files rather than using `git add .` which mean *add every thing found in current directory* — including your *imgs* folder.

Another option is to have a .gitignore file. You can list in this file any files/directories you don't want to be pickup by `git add`.

Also note that the `-a` option of `git commit` will not pickup files not currently tracked, i.e. never added.

Also that git will not ignore files already added. To remove them from being *tracked*, you can use `git rm --cached <file>` or `git rm --cached -r <directory>`. `--cached` tells `git rm` to **not delete** the actual file. `-r` tells `git rm` to recursively remove all files in the directory.